# Python, байты и числа в integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных

Осваиваю постепенно пайтон, пишу программу для общения с AVR контроллером через блютуз.

Из сокета я получаю данные в виде строки байт такого вида `b'\xb1\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf'`.

Так как я пишу свой протокол и работаю с разными типами данных (отправляю их с МК не в символьном виде), разбиваю строку на части, к примеру: `b'\xb1'`, `b\xaa\xab'` и `b\xac\xad\xae\xaf'`, то есть на однобайтовый int, двухбайтовый int и четырёхбайтовый int, с чем проблем не возникает.

Главная задача - преобразовать эти байтовые последовательности в исходные числа. Однобайтовый int вполне получается преобразовать так:

```
In [64]: line = b'\t\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf'
In [65]: line [0]
Out[65]: 9
In [72]: a = line [0]

In [73]: a
Out[73]: 9

In [74]: a += 1

In [75]: a
Out[75]: 10
```

Но вот метод преобразования в число двух и более бай мне неведом. В результате поиска больше запутался.
И так, вопрос: как имея в исходных данных байтовые строки вида `b\xaa\xab'` и `b\xac\xad\xae\xaf'` привести их к целочисленному типу данных?

Comment: какая версия pythonа?

Comment: Spyder, Python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы конвертировать байты в целое число в Питоне 3 в независимости от числа байт:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xb1', 'big')
177
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xaa\xab', 'big')
43691
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xac\xad\xae\xaf', 'big')
2897063599
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xac\xad\xae\xaf', 'big', signed=True)
-1397903697
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xac\xad\xae\xaf', 'little', signed=True)
-1347506772
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xac\xad\xae\xaf', 'little')
2947460524
```

Если много однотипных данных, можно `array.array`, `numpy.array` использовать для экономии памяти и [быстроты работы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805696/4279) векторных операций.

Если есть обрамляющая структура, то можно [прочесть данные, используя `struct.Struct`, `ctypes.Structure` (для struct из С)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244488/4279).

Comment: Спасобо, заработало! И да, массивы данных у меня в районе 3.5 килобайта/секунда.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону модуля struct, он как раз для этих задач. В Вашем случае:

```
import struct

line = b'\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf'
format = '<hi'
print(struct.unpack(format, line))

(-21590, -1347506772)
```

Я для простоты выкинул в строке line \t, но можно и с ним распарсить строку:

```
import struct

line = b'\t\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf'
format = '<Bhi'
print(struct.unpack(format, line))

(9, -21590, -1347506772)
```

Comment: Интересный подход. То есть мы задаём для парсера маску и он сам распаковывает данные... Не зря перешёл на python!